# Infinite AJAX Scroll - Infinite scrolling without extra html files

Tags: jquery-ias

In the examples of the Infinite AJAX Scroll script(www.infiniteajaxscroll.com), there are extra html files that are being used for pagination. I plan to have my items dynamically created on the page(through PHP). Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not (yet) supported by Infinite AJAX Scroll.